# mysql trigger partially working

Tags: mysql, triggers

My application requires 5 different categories of vehicles and each category of vehicle has some common fields. So what i did was created 5 tables for each of the 5 categories of vehicles `vehicle1`, `vehicle2`,`vehicle3`,`vehicle4`,`vehicle5`
and then created a 6th table 'vehicle' for storing fields which are common to each vehicle. Now whenever i enter info related to a particular vehicle which is an `INSERT INTO` that particular vehicle's category table, a trigger executes that inserts the common fields into the `vehicle` table. so the triggers look like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_vehicle1_info` AFTER INSERT ON `vehicle1`
 FOR EACH ROW insert into vehicle(categ,year,make,model,vin,user_id,principal_driver) values (1,new.year,new.make,new.model,new.vin,new.user_id,new.principal_driver) 

CREATE TRIGGER `tr_vehicle1_info` AFTER INSERT ON `vehicle2`
 FOR EACH ROW insert into vehicle(categ,year,make,model,vin,user_id,principal_driver) values (2,new.year,new.make,new.model,new.vin,new.user_id,new.principal_driver)

CREATE TRIGGER `tr_vehicle1_info` AFTER INSERT ON `vehicle3`
 FOR EACH ROW insert into vehicle(categ,year,make,model,vin,user_id,principal_driver) values (3,new.year,new.make,new.model,new.vin,new.user_id,new.principal_driver)
```

and so on .....

Now the problem is that when i insert info for a vehicle the trigger executes and the values are inserted in the table `vehicle` but for the `categ` field in the `vehicle` table always a `0` is inserted. the type of the `categ` field is `tinyint(1)`.

I dont understand whats wrong. Help?

UPDATE

schema of vehicle

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vehicle` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categ` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `year` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `make` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `vin` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `principal_driver` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondary_driver` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `vin` (`vin`,`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: can you show ouput of your table `desc vehicle`

Answer (score 1):

Your categ is defined as a single bit: "TINYINT(1)" allocates 1 bit to store the integer. So you can only store a 0 or a 1 in it. (EDIT: I am wrong about storage allocation, I misunderstood the documentation.) But I honestly don't understand why you're entering info "backwards." I would enter info into the master vehicle table and then link  the records to break out tables with columns specific to the vehicle category if you want to avoid a bunch of null entries — usually I just repurpose the empty fields based on the type of info to save space (if I'm not going to search via that info much, if at all) and only retrieve what I need. But I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, so I can't say for certain.

EDIT: Did it work, and if not what problems are you having? Here is what I would probably do (note: not complete, nor checked):

```
        CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logistics`.`vehicle` (
          `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
          `category` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL COMMENT '(4) Allows for 7 vehicle Categories' ,
          `v_year` YEAR NOT NULL ,
          `v_make` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
          `created` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
          `modified` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
        ENGINE = InnoDB;

            CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logistics`.`driver` (
          `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
          `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
          `middle_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT 'helpful in cases of 2 drivers with the exact same first and last' ,
          `sir_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
          `suffix_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT 'rather than \"pollute\" your sir name with a suffix' ,
          `license_num` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Always handy in case of claims, reporting, and checking with the DMV, etc.' ,
          `license_expiration` DATE NOT NULL COMMENT 'Allows status of driver\'s license report to be run and alert staff of needed to verify updated license' ,
          `license_class` CHAR(1) NULL COMMENT 'From what I know classes are \'A\' through \'D\' and usually a single letter. Helpful if needing to assign drivers to vehicles.' ,
          `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
          `modified` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
        ENGINE = InnoDB;
            CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logistics`.`driver_vehicle` (
          `vehicle_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
          `driver_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
          `principal_driver` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'FALSE' COMMENT 'if not specified it will be assumed the driver is not a primary.' ,
          `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
          `modified` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
          `admin_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
          PRIMARY KEY (`vehicle_id`, `driver_id`) ,
          INDEX `fk_driver_vehicle_driver1` (`driver_id` ASC) ,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_driver_vehicle_vehicle`
            FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id` )
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`vehicle` (`id` )
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE CASCADE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_driver_vehicle_driver1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`driver_id` )
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`driver` (`id` )
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE CASCADE)
        ENGINE = InnoDB;

        CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logistics`.`vehicle_options` (
  `vehicle_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `option_type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT 'if certain options are common you could pull by type of option i.e. cosmetic, cargo, hp, weight_capacity, max_speed, etc.' ,
  `option_value` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vehicle_id`, `option_type`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_vehicle_options_vehicle1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`vehicle` (`id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: BTW: I noticed you have 2 fields with essentially the same info: primary and secondary driver. Sure I understand that you need a "primary" for insurance, but what if a vehicle has more than 2 drivers? You would end up adding new columns, with some empty for vehicles with less drivers, and some overflowing. The strength of using a relational database is being able to normalize data and never run into that sort of problem.

Comment: only secondary driver can be multiple and so it is a varchar so i will store ids of secondary drivers in that field separated by a delimiter

Comment: tinyint(1) takes 1 byte not bit

Comment: No, you are wrong: TINYINT by itself is 1-byte. But if you define the column as TINYINT(1) you are explicitly saying you only want to use one bit of that byte. If you don't believe me look it up in the manual. Also, if you have multiple drivers in your secondary driver column searches for all the vehicles those drivers can drive will take longer because you'll be searching VARCHAR tables with a LIKE ## instead of just a JOIN… WHERE driver_id = "#".

Comment: you are right regarding the secondary drivers issue. Then what would you suggest? Use a separate table for secondary drivers

Comment: i read [this](http://www.phpmag.ru/2009/02/15/mysql-tinyint1-and-tinyint4-which-one-is-bigger/) and understood that tinyint(1) does not specify how many bits can be used. Its just like a mental reminder for how many bits you wanna use. The width, i mean `(n)` for numeric types does not hold any functional significance

Comment: Ah, okay. I read that BOOLEAN was equivalent to TINYINT(1), but after reading your link I see why. I would make a driver_vehicle table for the relationships and then join them on each lookup. If you made a varchar that was character delimited, you're essentially making a table in a single field that is less flexible than just making a table.

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct that any of the triggers in your code sample have the same name? I would suggest to check for typos in the original code.

Comment: if there was something wrong with trigger name then why all other fields would be entered